# List untested methods with Visual Studio or ReSharper

Tags: .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, resharper

Let's just say that once upon a time you had a nice tidy .NET code base with full test coverage, and it's since evolved a bit, and while all the existing tests still pass, there is a fair amount of new functionality that is untested.

Is there a straightforward way with either Visual Studio or VS + ReSharper to list the methods that *don't* currently have test coverage?

I contract with companies that use different test frameworks, so if it there is some framework agnostic solution that would be even better.

Comment: It would have been more helpful to very briefly explain why I'm being stupid than to down vote. I can do it manually and in a tedious fashion, but I'm wondering if there is some VS/RS feature that I've missed, as Googling didn't help much.

Comment: NCover do that, and it integrates nicely in VS using test-driven.net. Which is free or not, depending of your status.

Comment: You can use the code coverage tools that come with TestDriven.Net or NCrunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another tool called DotCover from the same guys who develop ReSharper (JetBrains). Also there are products from other developers, such as NCover or TestDriven.NET mentioned in comments.